# How to change a $scope variable inside a filter

Tags: angularjs

I need to change a `$scope` variable inside a filter. The `$scope` variable is used for a `ng-show` attribute and the information is only acceded in the filter because I have a `ng-repeat` with some information and applied by some filters and I need to know when the filters delete all my result to show a message... here is an example: (this is only an idea)

```js
.controller("thing", function() {
   $scope.showText = false;
})

.filter("filterText", function() {
   return function(information) {
     if (information == "") { /* NEED TO CHANGE $scope.showText to true */ }
   }
})
```

HTML:

```html
<div ng-view="showText"> Some Text here </div>
<div ng-repeat="info in information | filterText"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think a filter should access a controller and change information? Why should it? Isn't a controller action triggering if the showText should change?

Comment: You are heading down the wrong direction. I agree with @PetarMinchev, filters shouldn't be concerned or have access to controllers or scopes. By definition, filters are concerned only with the input data passed in could be reduced and nothing more. With the limited info given on what you are trying to achieve, from a high-level perspective, you should be using a one-way binding to monitor if the `information | filterText` is of length zero.

Comment: filters should never alter the data they are given, as this may cause multiple `$digest` cycles and slow down performance. Put whatever you need in a controller.

Comment: yes, I agree with you now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments that you probably don't want to be changing data in the filter in the first place but if you were really hard pressed you might be able to achieve this by just defining a filter function inside your controller (rather than an actual angular "filter") and then just use it as such:

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilter()"

$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
    // access to scope here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's code have small error: we need pass only function name to filter as below

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilter"

$scope.myFilter = function(item) {
    // access to scope here
}
```